# converting a canvas into bitmap image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am trying to develop an app on canvas,I am drawing a bitmap on the canvas. After drawing, I am trying to convert into bitmap image.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: You already get one bitmap object or you want to save this canvas in to a bitmap file?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Advice depends upon what you are trying to do.

If you are concerned that your controls take a long time to draw, and you want to draw to a bitmap so you can blit the bitmap rather than re-drawing via a canvas, then you *don't* want to be double-guessing the platform - controls automatically cache their drawing to temporary bitmaps, and these can even be fetched from the control using [`getDrawingCache()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29)

If you want to draw using a canvas to a bitmap, the usual recipe is:

1. Create a bitmap of the correct size using [`Bitmap.createBitmap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)
2. Create a canvas instance pointing that this bitmap using [`Canvas(Bitmap)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#Canvas%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) constructor
3. Draw to the canvas
4. Use the bitmap

Answer (score 27):

So you create a new `Bitmap`, for example:

`Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap( (int)Width, (int)Height, Config.RGB_565 )`

with `width` and `height` being the same as your canvas.

Next, use `canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap)`, but not `drawBitmap()`.

After you call `setBitmap`, all what you draw on canvas is in fact, drawing on your `myBitmap` going by the example code I have illustrated.

**Edit**:

You can not create a bitmap directly such as:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap( (int)Width, (int)Height, Config.RGB_565 );
```

You must use instead:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( (int)Width, (int)Height, Config.RGB_565 );
```

Comment: oh greate. Finnaly understud how it works from your answer. So can  i to cash some parts of my draw in bitmap and redraw already prepared bitmaps stored in some array as draw optimization via you describe? Wiil be good news

Answer (score 2):

Other example:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapNews(int item , boolean selected, int numbernews){                   
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if(selected)
            bitmap=mBitmapDown[item].copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        else 
            bitmap=mBitmapUp[item].copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        if(numbernews<10){
        canvas.drawBitmap(mNotiNews[numbernews],0,0,null);
        }else{
            canvas.drawBitmap(mNotiNews[0],0,0,null);
        }

 return bitmap; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Following are the steps to convert from canvas to bitmap and storing it to gallery or specific folder.**

Note: Make sure you have given permission of [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

**activity_main.xml**

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <DrawingView
                    android:id="@+id/drawingView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

1. **Create reference of parent layout**

   ```
   LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
   ```
2. **To store it into gallery**

   ```
   final String imagename = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
   MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), linearLayout .getDrawingCache(), imagename, "drawing");
   ```
3. **To convert into bitmap**

   ```
   linearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   linearLayout.buildDrawingCache();
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(linearLayout.getDrawingCache());
   ```