# converting canvas into bitmap in android

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap, rect

I am trying to develope an app on canvas ,i am drawing a bitmap on canvas with the help of canvas.drawBitmap().After that i want to convert that canvas into bitmap.

can anyone give me suggession

thanking you in advance

Comment: Do you need to display the canvas and save it to a bitmap? if you just need to draw to a bitmap then you can create the canvas with Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap); Then anything you draw to the canvas will be drawn onto the bitmap behind. (Make sure the bitmap behind is mutable though)

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a canvas into bitmap image in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

toDataURL() *would* be great, if it worked in Android.  Please star this issue!  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you look to the method toDataURL to obtain an image, but i doubt it while provide a bmp file, more likely to be png.

More info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: it would be the way to go, but android doesn't support `toDataURL`

Answer (score 0):

first of all these treat as a view including canvas and then here we need to use the screen capture concept of android we need to use a method decorView() and it returns a one bitmap object.