# Find text x,y position in canvas for android

Tags: android

I am currently doing such type of project. My requirement is how to find total x,y position used in writing text in canvas.

For example :

show in image, display on alphabets, I want to find total x,y points used to make A.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the bounding box, or the number of pixels that are red.

Comment: x,y position of red color A Text.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why would you need to do that, but here's some rude solution:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        if (color != BACKGROUND_COLOR) {
            result.put(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

You just loop through your bitmap and compare color of each pixel to background color. If it's different, you add current pixel to result map.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android) if you don't know how to retrieve `Bitmap` from `Canvas`

Answer (score 0):

Create custom class

```
public class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {

    private Rect rect;


    @Override
    public void drawPicture(Picture picture, Rect dst) {
        rect =dst;      
        super.drawPicture(picture, dst);
    }

    public Rect getRect() {
        return rect;
    }


}
```

Call CustomCanvas rect from

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        canvas.getRect().intersect((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY(),0,0);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```