# Is there Any Way To Get Drawn Text in Canvas Android

Tags: android, text, canvas, paint

I Need a Text which is drawn in a paint,Below i attached picture,i draw the letter "a" using `canvas` and `paint`,is there any possibilities to get the drawn text "a" from the canvas in android.[image: Picture]

Comment: get the image meaning you want to save or you want the text

Comment: @Raghunandan i need the drawn text as text

Comment: you are talking about OCR.

Answer (score 0):

you are drawing on a canvas. So after drawing you have to convert your canvas into bitmap.
check this link
[converting a canvas into bitmap image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android)