# how to change canvas with Drawable?

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

I need to convert the rotated canvas image to drawable.

Conversely, there are many ways to convert from drawable to canvas, but I could not find what I wanted.

Is it not common to convert from Canvas to Drawable?

Should I use another method?

Please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View v = new View(this);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.draw(canvas);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bitmap from your canvas as described in [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android), hen you can generate your BitmapDrawable this way `new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap)`