# How to convert a canvas drawing to an image then Drag it around screen?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to draw on a canvas then onClick change it to bitmap image then I would like to make it draggable. I can draw on canvas successfully 
but how do I convert this drawing to an image then make it draggable? I don't mind If it's possible to drag the drawing without converting to an image. Can someone please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    protected DrawView canvasView;
    private ImageButton blackCircle;
    private Button pens,select;
    private Paint mPaint;
    Bitmap viewCapture = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPaint = new Paint();

        canvasView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.canvas_view);//The drawing mechanism
        colorChanged(mPaint.getColor());

        blackCircle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.black_circle);           
        blackCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvasView.setPathColor(Color.BLACK));
                blackCircle.setPressed(true);
            }
        });

        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ic_select);
        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                canvasView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                canvasView.setPathColor(0);
                //Drag the drawn image
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
                drawingView = new DrawingView(MainActivity.this);
                relativeLayout.addView(drawingView);

                //Create a bitmap image of current drawing
                canvasView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                viewCapture = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasView.getDrawingCache());
                canvasView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
        });

    }// End of Create();

    private void clearCanvas(View v) {
        canvasView.clear();
    }       

@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    canvasView.setPathColor(mPaint.getColor());
}


/**************   OnTouch ***************/

class DrawingView extends View{
    float x,y;

    public DrawingView(Context context){
        super(context);
        viewCapture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.main);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x =(int)event.getX();
                y =(int)event.getY();
                invalidate();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x =(int)event.getX();
                y =(int)event.getY();
                invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(viewCapture, x, y, paint); 
    }
  }
}//End of Class


public class DrawView extends View {

private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private SparseArray<Path> paths;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    paths = new SparseArray<>();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawPath(paths.valueAt(i), drawPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int id = event.getPointerId(index);

    Path path;
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(event.getX(index), event.getY(index));
            paths.put(id, path);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for (int i=0; i<event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                id = event.getPointerId(i);
                path = paths.get(id);
                if (path != null) path.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            path = paths.get(id);
            if (path != null) {
                drawCanvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
                paths.remove(id);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void setPathColor(int color) {
    drawPaint.setColor(color);
}

public void clear() {
    canvasBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    paths.clear();
    invalidate();
    System.gc();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next steps I assume you'd like to let the users drag the picture which they just created with the `DrawView`. So I'd introduce another `View` which can display the bitmap and set its position and dimensions exactly like those of the `DrawView`. (The best way to achieve this depends on the type of `ViewGroup` you are using)

Create a bitmap from the canvas as shown in [converting a canvas into bitmap image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4013725/5015207)

Set the bitmap as the new `View`'s background with [setBackground(Drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), toggle the visibility of both `View`s as needed.

To make the new `View` draggable, use a `View.OnTouchListener` and change the position according to the `MotionEvent`s

Another option: just drag the `DrawView` by using a flag to indicate whether the users can drag it or draw on it. You override `onTouchEvent()` already, now check the flag first and if it is set to "drag" then evaluate the delta between two MOVEs and adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: My MainActivity class is updated now and works, a small issue though when image is dragged it's jumping and not a smooth drag, I'm not so sure how to achieve this ?

Comment: @Tony - there is some sample code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup) which suggests using something called "touch slop" . I think it's useful for achieving a smooth movement because it helps you to ignore small deviations from the general direction of the drag