# Convert Canvas to Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I have a canvas object and i'm searching for a method to draw a canvas into a Bitmap object like that:

```
Canvas canvas = ...;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: no, ther is no such way, however the opposite is available: `new Canvas(Bitmap)`

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? where do you have that `Canvas` object from?

Comment: this Canvas contains my whole interface, so this operation would be like get a screenshot as Bitmap

Comment: so you have some `draw(Canvas canvas)` method, right? then simply call it passing the `new Canvas(bitmap)`

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int drawableRes, Context context) {
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableRes);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
    drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
     Bitmap drawableBitmap = getBitmap(YourResource, mContext);
```

So you create a new Bitmap, with width and height being the same as your canvas.

```
  Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap( (int)Width, (int)Height, Config.RGB_565 )
  canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap)
```

but not drawBitmap

Comment: What should do I have to pass as drawableRes?

Comment: This may explain better than me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android

Answer (score -2):

Try this code :

```
Canvas canvas = ...;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas);

canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: where did you see such method: `Bitmap.createBitmap(Canvas)`?

Comment: The problem is that the createBitmap's method does not accept canvas as argument

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sense `createBitmap(`) method accept `bitmap` as a parameter, not `canvas`